How to reuse a set of property and logic in three different UI dialog next button based on UI dialog condition
In WIX, I have a common set of property and logic which needs to be executed in three different UI dialog next button. And the execution should be based on condition on that UI dialog. Like, if condition is true execute the common logic in that next button else don’t execute the logic and proceed with the other things.
How to achieve these in WIX.
How to separate the logic to different file.
How to include the separated file in three UI dialog
How to call the common logic based on the UI dialog condition (if certain checkbox selected in UI then execute the common logic)
